# The Fancybox "open" event got triggered on a click event, fired by an element which is inside the element binded to the Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, fancybox

I have on a div a Fancybox binded, inside of this div I have a "Delete" button, and when I click on the "Delete" button the fancyBox appears, but I don't want to appear at Delete. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.. You can put some code which handles the click event of Delete button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on button click-event is propagationing up from button, to div, to window.
You need first to catch and to stop propagation of `button` click event, for example:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(event){

    /*
    your code here
    */

    //stop event propagation 
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: What if both event handler was attached to the document with an "on" method? Then both event will be caught on the document (because of event bubbling), in this way the event.stopPropagation() not working, am I right?

Comment: @LóriNóda : nope, you can bind an event to a parent element and stop propagation to their children.

Answer (score 1):

[@Aleksandr Mochalygin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4102268/aleksandr-mochalygin) is correct when proposing to use `stopPropagation()`

So assuming you have an html like this

```
<div class="fancybox" data-fancybox-href="http://fancyapps.com/" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Some other content</p>
    <p>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

You could bind your `<div class="fancybox">` to fancybox without allowing the *delete* button (`class="delete"`) to fire fancybox with this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        // actions for delete button here
        alert("delete button was clicked");
        e.stopPropagation(); // don't fire fancybox
    }).fancybox();
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p6uombor/)**